# Xamarin iOS Binding Library View Controller Button Click Crashes Xamarin form App

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.ios, xamarin.android, xamarin.forms, xamarin-studio

I am creating a xamarin forms app in which a iOS binding library used on a button click in xamarin forms app a ViewController presented from binding library (i.e. declared and defined inside binding library) and in ViewController there is a navigation bar create programmatically in ios library.On bar button click library dismiss the ViewController in ios and Xamarin iOS also. But when I used this library in Xamarin forms app there is a crash on the same button click.
the followings are my Screen Shots of my crash logs:

[image: Exception]

and application output is as follows:
[image: Applicaion Output logs]

Application logs are:

```
 2016-09-20 13:10:33.270 TestXamarinFormApp.iOS[2923:95916] -[AppDelegate window]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7be3a0e0

    2016-09-20 13:10:33.275 TestXamarinFormApp.iOS[2923:95916] Xamarin.iOS: Received unhandled ObjectiveC exception: NSInvalidArgumentException -[AppDelegate window]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7be3a0e0
    Thread finished: <Thread Pool> #5
```

Can anybody solve this problem ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is due to Xamarin Forms App does not defines UIWindows in AppDelegate file so this issue can be resolved by adding following function in your AppDelegate File.

```
public override UIWindow Window {
 get { 
return UIApplication.SharedApplication.KeyWindow; 
      }
}
```